# Passing a function which returns void but has integer arguments to another function as an ARGUMENT itself

Tags: c++, function, callback, opencv, function-parameter

I have recently started working on **OpenCV** using **c++**. I am having a problem with the following code.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
int g_slider_position = 0;
CvCapture* g_capture = NULL;

void onTrackbarSlide(int pos) {
  cvSetCaptureProperty(
    g_capture,
    CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,
    pos
  );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  cvNamedWindow( "Example3", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  g_capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "Aawaarapan.avi" );
  int frames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(
    g_capture,
    CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
  );
  if( frames!= 0 ) {
    cvCreateTrackbar(
      "Position",
      "Example3",
      &g_slider_position,
      frames,
      onTrackbarSlide //need to be call as onTrackbarSlide(g_slider_position) but gives error:invalid use of void expression 
    );
  }

  IplImage* frame;
  while(1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame( g_capture );
    if( !frame ) break;

    cvShowImage( "Example3", frame );
    cvCreateTrackbar(
      "Position",
      "Example3",
      &g_slider_position,
      frames,
      onTrackbarSlide
    );

    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;

    ++g_slider_position;
  }

  cvReleaseCapture( &g_capture );
  cvDestroyWindow( "Example3" );
  return(0);
}
```

here the call to the function `cvCreateTrackbar` takes as argument, the function

`void onTrackbarSlide(int pos)`

but when I call the function like this
    cvCreateTrackbar(
      "Position",
      "Example3",
      &g_slider_position,
      frames,
      onTrackbarSlide(g_slider_position)
    );`

it is reporting an error
`error: invalid use of void expression`

Actually i need to pass the g_slider_position to the function so that the slider's position is known.

A friend of mine told me to call the function as

```
cvCreateTrackbar(
  "Position",
  "Example3",
  &g_slider_position,
  frames,
  onTrackbarSlide
);
```

this doesn't report any error but it doesn't do what it is supposed to.the slider's position is necessary.

So, my question is how do I call the cvCreateTracker with argument onTrackerSlide(with its integer argument). I hope I was not confusing.

Thank you!

Comment: Please tell me that you don't format all your code like that! I hope that it was just a copy-paste error.

Comment: Definitely confusing. If you're trying to pass g_slider_position, what are you doing with onTrackbarSlide()?

Comment: @Mark: Reindented (pfiuu) @CadetNumber1: you should make an effort when posting, unreadable questions are unlikely to get answers...

Comment: @jay G_slider_position is supposed to be passed to onTrackbarSlide which in turn is suppoesed to be passed to cvTrackbar

Comment: @CadetNumber1: you should brush up on pointers to functions and callbacks in C...

Comment: @eugen please provide any good link for the same...

Comment: @CadetNumber1: "doesn't do what it is supposed to do" is the same as "doesn't work". That doesn't say anything. It doesn't say what behavior you're expecting, or what it does that it shouldn't do, or what it doesn't do that it should. In some cases one see some obvious error in the code. In this case, one would need to be a telepath to deduce what the "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @alf actually that piece of code is supposed to modify the global variable g_slider_position.

Comment: You could have a look here: http://www.aishack.in/2010/02/highgui-creating-interfaces/

Answer (score 3):

`g_slider_position` is accessible to your function -- you can't pass it.  You should use the code you have (from your friend), but the int passed is the id of the trackbar.

Should be this:

```
void onTrackbarSlide(int id) {
  cvSetCaptureProperty(
    g_capture,
    CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,
    g_slider_position
  );
}
```

Comment: how could that be?  In the code you show, it's declared right above the function.  If you moved it to another cpp, then you need to extern declare it with `extern int g_slider_position;`

Comment: id is the id of the slider -- this is so you can share the same callback in multiple sliders.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of C function pointer usage, which I'm assuming you've never used.

At the point of creating the trackbar, you should indeed use:

```
cvCreateTrackbar(
  "Position",
  "Example3",
  &g_slider_position,
  frames,
  onTrackbarSlide
);
```

When you make that call, you are telling OpenCV two pieces of information:

1. the address of `g_slider_position`
2. the address of `onTrackbarSlide`

Now, when that trackbar is moved, OpenCV will:

1. modify `g_slider_position` directly (so you don't actually even need to receive it as a function parameter, but anyway)
2. call `onTrackbarSlide(g_slider_position)`, which it can do because it knows both pieces of information

If you write the code the way you were trying to:

```
cvCreateTrackbar(
  "Position",
  "Example3",
  &g_slider_position,
  frames,
  onTrackbarSlide(g_slider_position)
);
```

Where you wrote `onTrackbarSlide(g_slider_position)`, that turned into a function invocation of `onTrackbarSlide`.  In other words, while trying to figure out what values you wanted to pass to `cvCreateTrackbar`, it called `onTrackbarSlide` and passed it the current value of `g_slider_position`, and hoped that `onTrackbarSlide` would return a function pointer, because that's what it needed.  OK, it never got that far, because it could tell at compile time that `onTrackbarSlide` returned `void`, and that `void` was not `void(*aCallbackFunction)(int)` (which is how you specify the type "a function that takes an int and returns nothing"), but I'm using narrative style...

As for the `id` vs `position` argument, I can't speak from experience.  The docs I just read from willowgarage state that your callback receives the position, not the id, which means you have no way to use a single callback to differentiate between sliders.  I personally wouldn't want to do that anyway, 'coz it means I'd have one function with a switch instead of multiple functions.  Multiple functions will be (microscopically) more efficient, and definitely more readable.

On the other hand, `cvCreateTrackbar` does return an int, which might be the id of that trackbar.  Not sure what you're supposed to do with it, though.  The actual meaning of the return value was not defined on the doc page I just read.  Given that this is a C API and lacks a `bool` type, that `int` might just be a true/false return...